# Search Using 2 threads

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, search

'Is the threading correct in this code ?
I am searching a specific key in an array using 2 threads, one thread searches in first half of the array and second thread in second half of the array.'
I have created a struct named as Parameters which I fill with my parameters and pass it to the thread.
I made two Parameters objects to pass to two different threads.
Both have same array and same key, but starting point and ending point are different for both parameters because one thread has to search in first half and the other one has to search in second half.
starting point and ending point are set accordingly.

---

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define len 5



struct Parameters{
   int start;
   int end;
   int*arr;
   int key;
};

void* search(void* param)
{
   Parameters *pm = (Parameters*) param;
   int s = pm->start;
   int e = pm->end;
   int *A = pm->arr;
   int k = pm->key;
   bool flag = false;
   for(int i= s; i<e ;i++){
      if(A[i] == k){
         flag = true;
      }
   }

  pthread_exit( (void*) flag);

}

int main(int argc,char* args[])
{
  pthread_t id[2];

  int A[len] ;
  cout<<"Enter "<<len<<" elements \n";
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
     cin>>A[i];
  }
  Parameters p;
  p.arr = A;
  p.start = 0;
  p.end = len/2;
  p.key = 7;
  pthread_create(&id[0],NULL,&search,&p);

  Parameters p2;
  p2.arr = A;
  p2.start = len/2;
  p2.end = len;
  p2.key = 7;

  pthread_create(&id[1],NULL,&search,&p2);

  bool *found =  new bool(false);
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    pthread_join(id[i], (void**)found);
  }

  if(*found==true){
    cout<<"Found\n";
  }
  else{
    cout<<"Not found\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---